# “What do you think of” noun phrase

Tags: phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

[i] She thinks of herself as a poet.  ([Collins #7](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/think)) 
[ii] People are thinking of her for president. ([Webster’s, think of #2.b](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/think))
[iii] What do you think of the film?  ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/think_1?q=think))

It seems like verb *think* licenses two consecutive prepositional phrases [PP] as in [i] and [ii]. I’ve not yet found these constructions: ‘think + PP + Noun phrase’ or ‘think + PP + adjective phrase’. So I wonder if ‘what’ preposed from after ‘the film’ in [iii] would replace PP. Does *what* really replace PP, or is there any proper account?

Comment: For [iii] *"You think [great things] of the film"; "You think [highly] of the film".* Also, there's *"She thinks bad thoughts most of the time"; "She thinks all the time".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Think*, unless it's the intransitive 'display cognition' sense of Rodin's *The Thinker*,
is normally transitive, and its normal object is a complement clause describing the thought.

- *He thinks that the earth is flat*.  (tensed complement with *that* complementizer)
- *He never thought to get a permanent visa.*  (infinitive complement with [Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf))

Nouns are ungrammatical as objects for *think*, as are pronouns, unless they refer to a clause

- **He thinks the President/her/that one/somebody.*
- *He thinks it, whether he admits it or not.*

When a clause is not available, *think* can use prepositions and variant complement types
to target specific object types and specific thinking types

- *I'm thinking of one of Shakespeare's comedies.* ('have in mind')
- *I'm thinking of/about selling the motorcycle.*  ('consider V-ing; plan (on) V-ing')
- *I'm thinking my way around the obstacle.*  ('consider; ponder; analyze')
- *I think of him as my uncle.*  ('consider as')

Of the three example sentences,

(i) *She thinks of herself as a poet* is a 'consider as' construction.
 (ii) *People are thinking of her for president* is a 'consider V-ing' construction.
 (iii) *What do you think of the film?* is a 'consider as' construction, too.
   *What do you think of the film?* is the question from *You think of the film (as/in) what way.*

Comment: Would you class a cognate object (He had been thinking dark thoughts of late) as an exception to the above?

Comment: It's yet another construction; I'm not trying to be definitive here. Seems to be the same kind of VP extension as _give a push/shove, have a swim/drink,_ only with a cognate object NP instead of a small verb.

Comment: And your  "People are thinking of her for president is a 'consider V-ing' construction." Via  "People are thinking of making her president"?

Comment: @JohnLawler, Could I get to the point that yours is saying pronoun ‘what’ has adverbial/prepositional meaning in [iii]? Then can we say ‘how do you think of the film’?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yeah, probly something like that; it's an idiom and I didn't want to go into too much detail.

Comment: @Listenever: No, you can't say that. The idiom is ***What** do you think of X?*, not _How_. _How_ is used strictly for means and manner; it's not a general oblique pronoun. _How do you think he'll do it?_